# How to redirect - rewriten urls to short urls

Tags: url-rewriting, short-url, pretty-urls

I have changed my site url structure. But, Google indexed urls are giving 404 not found error. Now, I need a .htaccess rewrite rule for,

**From url:** www.mydomain.com/topic-titles-here-t273.html

**To url:** www.mydomain.com/sub-folder/topic273.html

(Topic id must be cached and topic title must be removed.)

Some times, like this also,

**From url:** www.mydomain.com/topic-titles-here-t273-15.html

**To url:** www.mydomain.com/sub-folder/topic273-15.html

I searched a lot, for about three hours, But couldn't find correct answer. Please help.

Comment: hostmonster web hosting, it is the case of a phpBB3 forum, mod_rewrite enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear on what you are trying to do but

1

```
RewriteRule    ^([a-z|-]+)(\d+\.html)$    /sub-folder/topic$2    [NC,L]
```

Would take the second group (just 273.html) and append accordingly, the first group would be 
everything before (topic-titles-here-t)

is that what you require? If so the regex could be tidied I just wanted to demonstrate the two groups

update - Ok according to edit the second group just becomes

```
(\d{3}-\d+\.html)
```

if 273 used in this example can be longer than 3 nubers if you know exact just amend that number otherwise use +

Comment: as per edit if the hyphen is there also would need to add that to the second group do you know exact number of digits in id?

Comment: Actually, the pages starts like 273.html, after five posts, the second page 273-5.html, third page 273-10.html and so on. I need to redirect all those indexed pages to be redirected to

Comment: I see no change! Nothing happens. Same 404 not found.

Comment: Sorry, The problem came because of some numbers present in url title text I tested, like www.mydomain.com/topic-51-titles-here-t273-15.html.

Comment: But, now also I'm getting another error: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." Checked url has no numbers in it's title text.

Comment: Ok if there are numbers in topic you can use t(\d{3}-\d+\.html) that will just match the last part in the first example specifically and may help the redirect not getting hit again

Comment: Again sorry, I added both the codes, that is the reason for firefox error. Ok, but, can you tell the answer for the urls with numbers in them, like www.mydomain.com/topic-51-titles-here-t273-15.html. Please.

Comment: Can't find any use with t(\d{3}-\d+\.html). Now, urls without numbers in topic titles are working fine, But, those with numbers are giving 404.

Comment: I checked and rechecked. It's working only if I hit tryagin button. As I couldn't post entire code here I posted it as a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057164/how-to-redirect-static-urls-to-small-urls

Comment: Finally I found solution:    `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9|-]+)t(\d+\.html)$ /redirect/topic$2 [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9|-]+)t(\d+-\d+\.html)$ /redirect/topic$2 [NC,R=301,L]` Anyhow, thankyou verymuch Shaun Hare.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9|-]+)t(\d+\.html)$ /redirect/topic$2 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9|-]+)t(\d+-\d+\.html)$ /redirect/topic$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```